# DnsEndpointIdentity Leads to Runtime Error System.NotImplementedException

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I am trying to establish a network connection between my Xamarin.iOS client and an existing SOAP service. For this I have to foresee the service's DNS identity in the client. The corresponding command is:

```
  DnsEndpointIdentity identity= new DnsEndpointIdentity("HelloWorldService");
```

Unfortunately, the command leads to a runtime error "**System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.**". The error is caused by the assignment of "HelloWorldService".

Object DnsEndpointIdentity belongs to assembly System.ServiceModel, which for iOS is available in version 2.0.5.0.

Everything looks fine for me and I have no clue what is going wrong.

May I ask you to help me?

Thank you very much,

Stefan

Answer (score 0):

In most cases with Xamarin, if you come across "System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented." it means that it has not been implemented in that current build of Xamarin.iOS. Unfortunately it's quite a common issue surrounding SOAP services, most notably with WCF Services which I work with. A lot of the time it requires creating custom headers for authentication. But again this depends on what works for you.